# Project movement from Main Dashboard to Custom Dashboard

Tags: sonarqube

Our SonarQube Server Version is  – 5.1. we have two dashboards (Main Dashboard & Custom Dashboard for specific project) was created by one of our X colleague.

Now we have requirement to add one project from Main Dashboard to Custom Dashboard. So for the same could you share the steps to complete this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use latest SonarQube LTS version, 5.6.
Then, you need to know that Dashboard have been removed since SonarQube 6.2